# Interceptor for SOAP request/response in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap

I am using springboot 2.5.4. I am calling a SOAP service from my code using the endpoint class that is generated from the WSDL.

Now I have a requirement that for each soap call I was to log the request and response. But I am not able to figure it our how to use that.

I tried a few examples that I got from the internet but it's not working. So can someone know how to implements this ?

**My Code**

**WSDL Class:**

```
@WebClient(targetNamespace="mynamespace", wsdlLocation="xx")
public class ServiceClient extends Service{
 // ,,,,

 @WebEndpoint(nmae="producer")
 public Producer getProducer(){
    return super.getPort(new QName(namespace:"mynamespace", localpart:"producer"),Producer.class));
 }

}
```

**Service Class**

```
class myService{

  method(){

  Producer p = ServiceClient.getProducer();

  // cal the service
  response = p.getData(request);

  }

}
```

**Interceptor**

```
public class CustomEndpointInterceptor implements EndpointInter{
 // implemented the methods
}

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class SoapServerConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {

        // register global interceptor
        interceptors.add(new CustomEndpointInterceptor());

        // register endpoint specific interceptor
        interceptors.add(new PayloadRootSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor(
                new CustomEndpointInterceptor(),
                "mynamespace",
                "producer"));
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you generating classes from your wsdl?

Comment: this is generated using wsimport available in openjdk, as I cannot find any plugin which can do automatically in gradle

Comment: There are many maven plugins that can do that.  For example, org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin